# How to prevent string auto escaping?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `var a = '\204444'`, and I want to remove `\`. I need the result to be `204444`.

I tried using `a.replace(/\\/g, '')`, but the result is not what I wanted.

Comment: There is no ``\`` in `a`. If your variable is supposed to have a backslash followed by the number `204444`, then define `a` as `var a = '\\204444'`. Currently, your string consists of `\204`, the octal sequence for the `U+0084` control character, followed by the number `444`. See [the documentation for escape sequences of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation). You cannot “prevent” this escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the variable initialisation you can do this

```
var a = String.raw`\204444`;
a.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

---

If you don't you can do this (**but that doesn't work if you have leading 0s**)

```
var a = '\2304444';
a.charCodeAt(0).toString(8) + a.replace(/^./g, '');
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am thinking that What should I do when the backslash can not keep the position, or have multiple backslashes.

Comment: as Sebastian pointed out the \ indicates the start of an octal sequence. Javascript then converts it to the corresponding character. If we know which position the octal sequence is at we can replace it by the sequence. But if we don't, it becomes difficult to distinguish between the octal sequence and actual characters. eg. `'\101A' === 'AA'`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code snippet to check, it only work with string have escaped first char.

```js
var a='\204444'; 
a=a.replace(a[0], a.charCodeAt(0).toString(8))
console.log(a)
```